# react router with different htmls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, components, react-router

I want to use react router to handle diffrent routes, the problem is every route has it's own html ( consider bootstap grid system, everypage has its own layout )
Is it possible to load diffrent html skeleton for diffrent route and attach components to corresponding container?
An alternative solution is to have a generic html and put grids in every compnent, but this soloution lowers component reuaabilty
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You mind sharing how your HTML looks like? I'm not sure if you have separate HTML files or if you're using JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route config, just make each path that you want to have it's own containing layout a root Route. Any sub-routes will get the html skeleton from the base component.

```
modules.export = [
    <Route path="firstSkeleton" component={FirstSkeleton}/>,
    <Route path="secondSkeleton">
        <Route path="home" component={SecondSkeleton}/>
    </Route>,
    ...
    <Route />
]
```

Each of the above Routes can have it's own layout defined in the root component, and then the subroutes will takeover from there and inherit.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a generic example of a blog with home page at the root of your app (`'/'`). It uses a generic **`Layout`** parent component and nests the **`HomePageLayout`** component as a child of **`Layout`**.

When you navigate to `'/blog'`, **react-router** generates the **`BlogListLayout`** component inside of the **`BlogLayout`** "template" by default. If you go to a specific blog such as `'/blog/some-user-blog'`, the **`BlogEntryLayout`** will render instead and it will still be nested in the **`BlogLayout`** template.

The `'/about'` route is an example of a simple page with no nested children components but you can see how easily you can add subroutes using **`IndexRoute`** and more **`Route`** components.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePageLayout}/>
      <Route path='/profile/*' component={ProfilePageLayout}/>
    </Route>

    <Route path='/blog' component={BlogLayout}>
      <IndexRoute component={BlogListLayout}/>
      <Route path='/*' component={BlogEntryLayout}/>
    </Route>

    <Route path='/about' component={AboutLayout}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```